# Angular universal Server Side Rendering, Meta tags

Tags: angular, meta-tags, angular-universal

I moved my site to Angular universal SSR,
during my move I encountered some problems that I thought ng-universal would fix.

I want to add meta tags such as description, keywords etc (different for each page).

Using the `titleService` as angular suggests works just fine, it changed the title of the pages. However if I land on homepage and then navigate from there to other pages, the title is not changing, but when I look on source I see the change in the source but no on the tab of VIEW. If I land on the page (or hit refresh) the page is updated with the correct title.

I tried  to add in additional to the title meta tags, but nothing works:

```
this.meta.updateTag( {name: "description", content: 'test1234});

this.meta.addTag({name: 'description', content: 'Content description' });
```

OR

```
using vanilaJS
 var doc = (<HTMLMetaElement>document.getElementById('description'));
doc.content = "test1234";
```

the meta is not changing in the header section.
I have no idea why.
any help can assist..
thanks

Comment: see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lncsmB5yfzE
 might be helpful, I followed the same and it works for me. make sure you are using the correct version of angular-cli and angular.

Comment: Did you figure it out why this was happening? I've the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To set meta tags for Angular Universal-SSR (tried only on Angular 2), you should use Renderer.
To set for example title(or update it), you can do it on this way: [Link for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58916653/9216932)

To set meta tags, you need to:
1.Import Renderer and Document

```
import { Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

2.Add these dependencies to constructor:

```
@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,
private renderer: Renderer
```

3.Add meta tags
-example

```
//-- Create new meta element inside of head tag
let elem = renderer.createElement(document.head, "meta");

//-- Set meta attributes
renderer.setElementAttribute(elem, 'name', 'description');
renderer.setElementAttribute(elem, 'content', 'Some test decription');
```

4. When you open "view page source", it should result like this inside of head tag:

   < meta name="description" content="Some test description" >

Comment: Do you see it working for dynamic data as well? like api call on OnInit?

Comment: Same issue for me. Dynamic meta tags are not working. If the meta tags are hardcoded then it works.